# Avoiding collisions with modules with same method names

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am thinking of using the following perl modules from Cpan:

[CSS-Minifier](http://search.cpan.org/~pmichaux/CSS-Minifier-0.01/lib/CSS/Minifier.pm)
[Javascript-Minifier](http://search.cpan.org/~zoffix/JavaScript-Minifier-1.12/lib/JavaScript/Minifier.pm)

I note from the documentation that I need to call the "minify" method for both.
I know I must be missing something obvious as a Perl newbie, but wouldn't they collide?

I suppose the question is how do I specify the "minify" for each module separately so that the CSS module works on CSS only and the JS module works on JS only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl modules include subroutines. Usually, the reason to use a module is to make use of the subroutines from that module. A module will have its own package name and the subroutines from that module will exist in that package. So a simple module might look like this:

```
package MyModule;

sub my_sub {
  print "This is my sub\n";
}
```

If I load that module in my code, then I have to call the subroutine using its fully qualified name (i.e. including the package name).

```
use MyModule;

MyModule::my_sub();
```

That gets repetitive quite quickly, so many modules will **export** their subroutines into your package. They do that using special arrays called `@EXPORT` and `@EXPORT_OK`.

If I put the name of a subroutine into `@EXPORT` then it automatically gets imported whenever that module is used.

```
package MyModule;

our @EXPORT = ('my_sub');

sub my_sub {
  print "This is my sub\n";
}
```

I can then use it like this:

```
use MyModule;

my_sub();
```

Alternatively, I can use `@EXPORT_OK` which defines optional exports. Users can ask for subroutines in `@EXPORT_OK` to be imported - but it doesn't happen automatically. You ask for an option export to be imported by including the name in the `use` statement.

```
package MyModule;

our @EXPORT_OK = ('my_sub');

sub my_sub {
  print "This is my sub\n";
}
```

I can now do this:

```
use MyModule ('my_sub');

my_sub();
```

There's one more trick that might be useful. You can turn off automatic imports with an empty list on the `use` statement. Assume we have the `@EXPORT` version of the module:

```
use MyModule (); # Turn off imports

my_sub(); # Doesn't work
MyModule::my_sub(); # works
```

Now we have the knowledge we need to look at your specific problem. The simplest solution is to turn off all automatic imports and use the fully-qualified names of both of the subroutines.

```
use CSS::Minifier ();
use JavaScript::Minifier();

CSS::Minifier::minify();
JavaScript::Minifier::minify();
```

But we can be a bit cleverer. The documentation for both modules suggests that both imports are optional so that you need to explicitly import the subroutines.

```
use CSS::Minifier ('minify');
use JavaScript::Minifier('minify');
```

This would obviously be a bad thing to do, as you can't import two subroutines with the same name!

However, looking at the source code to the modules, I see that the documentation for JavaScript::Minifier is wrong (**Edit:** I've [submitted a report](https://github.com/zoffixznet/JavaScript-Minifier/issues/4) about this error). CSS::Minifier has this line of code:

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(minify);
```

But JavaScript::Minifier has this:

```
our @EXPORT = qw(minify);
```

So the export is automatic from JavaScript::Minifier and optional from CSS::Minifier. So the simplest approach to take would be:

```
use JavaScript::Minifier; # Automatically imports minify
use CSS::Minifier; # Doesn't import option export minify
```

You could then use the two subroutines like this:

```
minify(); # Automatic export from JavaScript::Minifier
CSS::Minifier::minify(); # Fully-qualified name from CSS::Minifier
```

I suspect, however, that this is a bad approach as it's hard to be sure where the unqualified version of `minify()` comes from. I'd therefore recommend turning off all imports from the two modules and using the fully-qualified names for both subroutines.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and detailed answer. Accepting this instead.

Answer (score 2):

To call it separately if both [exported](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html), use :

```
CSS::Minifier::minify();
```

or

```
JavaScript::Minifier::minify();
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'd guess it's because you can call subroutines with fully qualified names whether or not they are exported.

Comment: Wasn't me either. Upvoted your answer but accepting that from Dave Cross for clarity and detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fully qualified names to reference subroutines and remove ambiguity.  And create shorter names with aliases.

```
use CSS::Minifier;
use JavaScript::Minifier;

BEGIN {
   *minify_css = \&{CSS::Minifier::minify};
   *minify_js  = \&{JavaScript::Minifier::minify};
}

minify_css(...);
minify_js(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. Useful tip on the aliases!